# How to host media files to be streamed?

Tags: delphi, streaming, indy

I'm building a simple web server using `TIdHTTPServer`. As usual, I can handle requests for files on the server machine, and I pass those files back via `TFileStream`...

```
if FileExists(Doc) then begin
  FResponse.ContentType:= FileMimeType(Doc); //Returns 'audio/mp3'
  FS:= TFileStream.Create(Doc, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  FResponse.ContentStream:= FS;
end else begin
  FResponse.ResponseNo:= 404;
end;
```

This works fine, and I am able to stream audio/video directly into an HTML5 web page.

The problem arises when the user attempts to skip forward into the track - it always jumps back to the beginning of the file. It seems the method of returning the file stream as shown above doesn't work 100% for real-life streaming. When using IIS to host such media, for example, everything is perfect, and the user can freely skip through the media file to any spot they wish. Just when using Indy to host the same file(s), it jumps back to the beginning.

Even after a range of the media file has been buffered into the media player, and user tries to jump to somewhere in the buffered data, it still jumps back to the beginning.

How should I properly host media files using Indy in a way that a user can skip through the track, as it works when hosted via IIS?

Comment: Kudos to Indy, but is there a practical reason to leave IIS in this case?

Comment: @Victoria Yes, for portability. The only reason I tried IIS at all was just to experiment. Otherwise, I don't tend to use it. I typically write web servers as stand-alone Services. I also don't want anyone else to be required to install/configure IIS to be able to use it. The entire project is used in a single HTML file, not even a complete website. So I'm not really "leaving" IIS in the first place :-)

Comment: I see, but still, I would personally tend to setup an existing one rather than rolling my own. I wish you good luck though! :)

Comment: Just an educated guess: When you skip, the request is made for a specific file offset/range, and you need to only return that part of the file that has been requested. You also need to - in your reply to the request - specify which part of the file you _actually_ returned. The code above always returns the entire file (and tells that), so the player - if it were to enforce the requested skipped-to-place - wait for your server to return all the bytes leading up to the skipped-to-place before resuming playback. By only returning the file data from the offset requested, you eliminate that delay.

Comment: HeartWare is right. You need to handle range requests, and if detected then returned a range response. The `IdCustomHTTPServer` unit even has a `TIdHTTPRangeStream` class to help with that.

Comment: @Remy looks like that's precisely what I'm missing here.

Comment: I suspected that. I was just in kinda high hopes that Indy would do most of it for me, since I pass the raw TFileStream over to it. Technically, it doesn't need to pass the *entire* file. Just a stream as fast as it can download.

Comment: @Remy Thanks, I didn't see that dupe before. Works perfectly now.